# attrib/chmod on old dos version

Tags: permissions, dos, chmod, dir

I'm working on an old pc with dos 5.0 installed.
I have plugged in a storage media on it, PC can easily see the directories and files, but i cannot overwrite or add directories/files.

So, if i would like to change permissions to one directory, how can i do this?
I have tried with: `attrib +a +r a:\DIR1 /s /d`
[but the /d option is not enabled on this old version of `attrib` and so it doesn't work]
I tried to download a latest version of `attrib`, but it gave me the message "DOS version not supported".

The moral is that i would like to do the same of linux's CHMOD in DOS 5.

I really need your help! i have searched in every site (google ecc.) but i didn't succeeded in finding the right solution.

thanks, have a nice day

dimakx

p.s.=if you know a third party software , too, that works in DOS 5 and could help me, please: notify me :)

Answer (score 0):

What sort of storage media is this?  Is it something that could be hardware write-protected (e.g., a floppy disk)?

Comment: The storage media is another hdd inserted into a free slot. I don't know if it is harware write-protected, how could i understand it (Which command)?

Comment: If you do `attrib A:\*` (or pick another location that has files you're interested in), does it show that the files are actually read-only?

Comment: yes, it shows only the files, but i want to  change directories permissions, not files.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I don't believe MS-DOS supports changing the permissions on a directory itself - just the files within them.